# ASP.NET Chat Application

Tags: asp.net

I am designing an asp.net web application. I need to list all logged in users to a list and click each of them to talk. Which control should I use for listing users? E.g. buttons in listview ? How can I do that ?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create custom user control and add buttons (or any other control) dynamically. [Dynamically Create Controls in ASP.NET by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794)